# Google API Permissions:create; Custom Message not appearing

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to have a custom message be sent when adding permissions to a file, while the invitation gets sent, the custom message does not appear. This is my snippet if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, I'd appreciate it =)
(Python3.7)

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def set_permissions(file_id):
        permissions = {
            "type": "user",
            "role": "writer",
            "emailAddress": 'my-email@domain.com',
            "sendNotificationEmail" : True,
            "emailMessage" : "some message with URL string"
        }

        service =  build('drive', 'v3', credentials=Auth(), cache_discovery=False)
        request = service.permissions().create(
            fileId= file_id,
            body=permissions,
            fields='id'
        )
        return request.execute()
```

I've tried going through the docs here : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

But don't see any typos in the field names or anything.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to create a permission using Drive API v3.
- You want to add `emailMessage`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with python.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
def set_permissions(file_id):
        permissions = {  # Modified
            "type": "user",
            "role": "writer",
            "emailAddress": 'my-email@domain.com',
        }

        service =  build('drive', 'v3', credentials=Auth(), cache_discovery=False)
        request = service.permissions().create(
            fileId= file_id,
            body=permissions,
            fields='id',
            sendNotificationEmail=True,  # Added
            emailMessage="some message with URL string"  # Added
        )
        return request.execute()
```

#### References:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)
- [Drive API . permissions](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.permissions.html)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for your answer.  While you understood the problem correctly, putting the arguments in the function still produces the same results.  I'm starting to think it's something with the library.

Comment: @tbb Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, in my environment, I could confirm that when I run the modified script, the custom message can be sent. So, I cannot replicate your situation. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the version of googleapis for Python you are using? And also, can you provide your whole script for replicating your current issue without removing your personal information? By this, I would like to think of the reason of your current issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.