# Google Drive v3 API 'sendNotificationEmail'

Tags: python, api, drive

I am creating new folders for our customers on Google Drive. But every time we create a new folder it sends notifications to them. I dont want them to receive notification. Yet with the code below its still sending notification.

I am using this code and it does not seem to block Notifications.

```
new_permission = {
  'role': role,
  'sendNotificationEmail' : False,
}
```

The Google Drive definition says that the file 'sendNotificationEmail' is a boolean.
And in Python you give False (with capital F) to indicate boolean false.
But this does not seem to stop sending notifications.

I also noticed that:
for Google Drive v2 it was 'sendNotificationEmails'
and for Google Drive v3 it is 'sendNotificationEmail'

Could someone please help, how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

See solution here, to put the parameter
`sendNotificationEmail=True`
in the create() method instead of in the permissions:
[Google API Permissions:create; Custom Message not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237340/google-api-permissionscreate-custom-message-not-appearing)